# Bootstrap seems to apply a smaller size to checkboxes in wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a wordpress plugin. When I import bootstrap from //stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
there is a couple of checkboxes which shrink down to 8x8.
I have used the devtools to work out that in scaffolding.less there is html font-size being set to 10px which is under 'Inherited from html.wp-toolbar.
If I turn this off in the devtools (even though its crossed out) the the checkbox returns to its normal size. Is it possible to override this in css or even the html directly somehow?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can try to override the CSS.

1. Place the required CSS rule after bootstrap css
2. Use !important to override
3. Use inline styles in html file

Comment: Thanks, I had been attempting to override the checkbox type and had added a class to the div around it. Added a class to the checkbox itself and then overrode the height and width as 1.4rem and also had to use !important as suggested.